# inserting user selection from one dropdown menu to mysql query used to generate dropdown menu items for the next dropdown menu list on same page

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu

so, after wracking my brains for two days now and doing my research on this topic, I have been unable to come to come to a solution to my problem. Here we go..

My html form has 4 drop down menus(html selects) whose options are populated from their respective tables in the database. However, each SQL query depends on the user selection from previous user selection. I will insert this user selection into the WHERE clause of the next SQL query. Please note that that the SQL should be processed before normal page sending, so I can't simply process sent requests. So how do I capture this user selection and insert into the sql query with PHP?

I hope my explanation is good enough. Any clues or tips would be highly appreciated. All I need to understand is how to capture the user selection and passing it to query, before clicking on the submit button Thank you.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly (which I'm not sure that I am) ... you just need to monitor the first select box for a change, and then use the new value to make an ajax call to your php script, which will send back the contents to be inserted into the next select menu.  Are you using jquery?  Take a look at the change event: http://api.jquery.com/change/.  When jquery detects a change to the first menu, load "selectItems.php" or whatever via ajax, and then plop that data into the second select.

Comment: This is a good case for using AJAX - Javascript intercepts the selection in the first listbox, fires off a PHP request to get the data and populates the next listbox, etc. jQuery works well for this. I'm sure other people can give you more detail.

Comment: Sounds plausible. In short, I should acquaint myself with jquery and ajax. I only have minimal knowlege of Javascript. Let me take a look at some tutorials, then get back with a code attempt at this.I think, only then can I follow better what you guys are saying.

Answer (score 0):

To me it would seem you have two options:

1. Query all possible combinations of data and load all select options onto page on initial page load.  Hide all options in selects 2, 3, and 4 initially, and just unhide appropriate options via javascript as selections are made.  This might be a good solution if you have a small number of options to where pre-loading them all is not a big hit to the page load time.
2. Load only the options for the first drop down on initial page load.  As selections are made, use AJAX to load in an appropriately filtered list of options for subsequent selects.  This might be a better option if you have large numbers of options or option combinations, to where you don't want to ever load all of them to the page.

Either way, there is no solution to do what you want purely with PHP unless you want page loads in between each individual selection event.